# message.author.id keeps getting undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to do a scoreboard for my quiz command, in a way that the person runs the command !quiz, and answers the question. If the question is answered correctly, in a specific file named Storage she gets one extra point, in so making a scoreboard for the amount of answers the has gotten correctly. I have watched a youtube tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dYpaV_pzGTA&t=271s) for the Scoreboard file, but the author's id keeps being determined as `undefined`, not allowing me to store all of the points.

For reference, here is my code

```
//Base...
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

//Quiz event...
client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;
    if (message.channel instanceof Discord.DMChannel) return message.channel.send('Aqui não podem ser executado comandos!')
        .then(msg => {
            msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 })
        })
    const quiz = require('./quiz.json');
    const item = quiz[Math.floor(Math.random() * quiz.length)];

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const filter = response => {
        return item.answers.some(answer => answer.toLowerCase() === response.content.toLowerCase());
    };

    if (message.content === '!quiz')
        message.channel.send(item.question).then(() => {
            const userData = fs.readdirSync('./Storage').filter(file => file.endsWith('.json'));

            fs.writeFile('Storage/userData.json', JSON.stringify(), (err) => {
                if (err) console.error(err);
            })

            if (!userData[message.author.id]) userData[message.author.id] = {
                rightQuizAnswers: 0
            }

            message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} acertou!`)

                    userData[message.author.id].rightQuizAnswers++
                })
                .catch(collected => {
                    message.channel.send('Parece que ninguém acertou :(  (Bando de buro)');
                });
        });

})
```

And the quiz is working fine, the only problem is that I the file that was suppost to have the points being stored like this:

```
{(the author's ID:{rightQuizAnswers:(number of questions guessed correct)}}
```

are only being responded with a:

```
undefined
```

To even turn it into a worse problem, when I substituted the 'message.author.id' with my ID, so that it would add a point to rightQuizAnswers, it still returned with `undefined`...

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really dive deep into your code, but it looks to me that it might be something wrong with either the JSON file, that should contain at least `{}` as starting content or rather something wrong with the file reading/saving. I tried to optimize the reading/saving, everything else is the same, so here's the code:

```js
const userDataPath = path.resolve(__dirname, './Storage/userData.json');

function loadUserData() {
  return JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(userDataPath).toString());
}

function saveUserData(userData) {
  fs.writeFileSync(userDataPath, JSON.stringify(userData, null, 2));
}

message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
  .then(collected => {
    const userData = loadUserData();

    message.channel.send(`${collected.first().author} acertou!`);

    if (!userData[message.author.id]) {
      userData[message.author.id] = {
        rightQuizAnswers: 0
      };
    }

    userData[message.author.id].rightQuizAnswers += 1;
    saveUserData(userData);
  })
  .catch(collected => {
    message.channel.send('Parece que ninguém acertou :(  (Bando de buro)');
  });
```

In other for this to work, if you haven't already, you should require 'path' just as you required fs.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path'); // Add this
```

Comment: I tried this out, and the command still doesn't work, it doesn't register the user's data, and now the .catch(collected => { message is being shuffled with .then(collected => {

Comment: What's inside ```userData.json```? Is it empty?

Comment: Yes, it is empty.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Please, write opened and closed brackets (```{}```) and then save the file.

Comment: It would not be recognized as JSON text otherwise, you could do a code for that, of course, but this way is just much simpler and easier to do.

Comment: Ok! It works!!! I am sorry to question this, but why do I need to leave a ```( {} )``` in the file?

Comment: It's okay, no problem = ). Because it would not be recognized as JSON Object otherwise. Your question implied that you wish to use a JSON Object for storage. That being said, even though the file has the .json extension, ```JSON.parse``` don't build an object out of nothing, it has to have at least the basic object. I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, maybe [this](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4042/o-que-%C3%A9-json-para-que-serve-e-como-funciona) can give you some idea.

Comment: Basically, _trying_ to be clear, fs.readFile returns a buffer of the text content of the file, so converting to string, if it is empty, ```JSON.parse``` does not parse it into a Javascript Object, because it won't even be recognized as a JSON (in which it will throw a syntax error). So it has to be at least either an object or an array.